# Do special variables maintain their existence in function calls in other required modules?

Tags: perl, require

I'm not a perl expert and I don't quite get how all of perl's scoping rules work.
I'm setting an $ENV{'whatever'}  environment variable, then I'm calling a function in another source .pl file and trying to read that ENV entry, and I'm getting nothing back. Docs say everywhere that ENV persists for the current process and any forked children, but is access to the %ENV variable available in other source files?

The source file was included via a 'require' command. Is that the right way to do it, or is there something static (first time in) about how variables are made available when a source file is required?

Comment: feel free to add your little test program to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%ENV` is a global, so it is accessible from everywhere in every source file loaded into a process.

`%ENV` is *inherited* when a new process is created with a `fork` but the new process gets its own copy so any changes made in one will not be visible in the other.

If you're loading the other source file with `do` or `require` or `use` then it's being loaded into the same process and it will see the same `%ENV`.

However if you're loading the new script with `system` or `exec` then the new script is loading in a new process and it will get its own copy of `%ENV`.

Comment: I believe you. It's doing that in a test program I just wrote, but it's not working in my real (huge legacy) program. Herumph. Can you think of anything that would interfere with that functionality that I can look for to see if something is blowing it away? Some other package, like CGI or something like that?

Comment: AHA I got it. there weren't quotes around the 'whatever' in the $ENV{'whatever'} Lord knows how it worked, but I am not the lord so I don't know. Thanks for confirming my understanding.

Comment: @stu, whatever you had in place of `whatever` was being executed as a Perl expression. You obviously had something that was an indentifier, because `$ENV{ident}` is a perfectly acceptable alternative to `$ENV{'ident'}`.

Answer (score 1):

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> ```
> %ENV
> ```
>
> The hash `%ENV` contains your current environment. Setting a value in
>   ENV changes the environment for any child processes you subsequently
>   `fork()` off.

---

`require`-ing a .pl file is not the same as forking a command.

It would be simpler to just set the necessary environmental variables through a Bash wrapper:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash

export whatever="/usr/bin/some_dir/";  # Set to env

perl script.pl;                        # Invoke the script

$ cat script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

print $ENV{whatever};                  # wrapper.sh : "/usr/bin/some_dir/"
                                       # script.pl  : ""
```